# Android Material SearchBar UI issue

Tags: android, layout, material-ui, searchview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to implement a Screen that has a material `SearchBar`.

I followed this documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/search/SearchBar

but I'm getting a warning over this line
`app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` that's telling me `searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior` is marked as private in `material:1.8.0` lib.

But the **Material Components Doc.** tells me that `SearchBar` is available starting from `1.8.0-alpha03` - [link here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md)

So when I'm using the `app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` then my `RecyclerView` gets placed behind the `SearchBar` like in the image bellow:

[image]

And when I change it to `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` I get the right positioning of my `RecyclerView` but my `SearchBar` doesn't look as it should anymore.

[image]

How can I have a proper positioning of my `RecyclerView` and a normal display of `SearchBar` at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to find a workaround on this by replacing `CoordinatorLayout` with `ConstraintLayout` and instead of hooking the `searchView` to the `searchBar` by using: `app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar"` I've hooked them programmatically by calling:

`searchView.setupWithSearchBar(searchBar)`

When I'm initializing the `views` within my `Fragment`class.